# ServiceStack: Impossible to use SOAP with custom namespace when AuthFeature is enabled?

Tags: soap, servicestack

I have a need to host a couple SOAP12 messages in my current SS webapi. I have set up all of the namespaces according to the rules and everything works as expected, to some extent. I can use multiple tools to send SOAP to the service(s) and they work. I have successfully added them as a Service Reference in a Visual Studio project where they work; at least until I add the AuthFeature. As soon as I add the AuthFeature or any other native SS service, I can no longer add the Service Reference.

My investigation has lead me to the namespace difference between the DataContract(s) in the ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth namespace used in the AuthService. I don't want this to be just limited to AuthService though, the same is applicable when the SwaggerFeature is added and the Resources service is set up.

It is imperative that these two messages be available in SOAP and the client must have the ability to add them as a Service Reference to consume them.

My question: Is there any way to set the DataContract namespace(s) for the native SS services so as to keep their namespace consistent with our DataContract namespace? I understand that I "could" compile and maintain my own version of SS where I would have the ability to change the ContractNamespace attributes of those causing issues however that would cause a lot of undo pain in maintenance especially when attempting to keep SS updated from its original source.

I realize that attributes ([DataContract]) are compile time constants basically and when ServiceStack is compiled the namespace is getting set. I am looking for any alternatives...

Taken from my AppHost:

```
SetConfig( new EndpointHostConfig
            {
                MetadataTypesConfig = new ServiceStack.Common.ServiceModel.MetadataTypesConfig(
                    addDefaultXmlNamespace: Namespaces.Services.NS_2013_01 ),
                WsdlServiceNamespace = Namespaces.Services.NS_2013_01,
                WsdlSoapActionNamespace = Namespaces.Services.NS_2013_01,
                //WsdlServiceTypesNamespace
            } );
```

Taken from my AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace( "Foo", ClrNamespace = "MvcApplication1.ServiceInterface" )]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a "hack" where you do the reversed, the buildin services will default to the namespace

```
 http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ServiceStack
```

so instead of trying to use your own namespace, use their namespace.